# Volume Slider Widget - Home and or Lock screen(s)

Tags: app-widgets, volume-control, water-damage

I recently replaced the micro-USB port on my Galaxy Nexus (GSM version, running 4.1.2) after it corroded due to water damage. During that process, I accidentally ruined the connection to the volume rocker while removing a board (I expected it to be be on a connector; turns out it was soldered...).

Unsurprisingly, the volume rocker no longer works. I don't have the necessary skill to resolder the ribbon, so I'm looking for something (a widget) that will let me control the volume from my home screen, or better yet from both the home screen and the lock screen.

I want to change the notification, music, and call volumes as easily as possible without the hardware rocker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to be rooted to control from home screen.

[Button Savior Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smart.swkey) will do this for you.

You can also download and install [Volume Control +](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cb.volumePlus) which allows you.to.modify the volume without a rooted device - you will have to use the widget or app UI however.

Comment: Cheers. Both of these are vastly better than nothing.

Comment: neither of those apps are on the playstore anymore.... any newer suggestions? Thanks